# Programmatically get TFS user's folders permission

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to get a User's access to folders along with list of permissions on that folder. 
Trying to do something similar to TFS command:

> TF Permissions "$MyRepository/MyFolder" /r

Till now, I'm able to get the list of the users, list of all sub folders and then query all those sub folders for each of the user for its permissions and checking for "checkin or merge". Here is my working code:

```
string TfsRepository = "$/Some/Base/Repository";
TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("https://tfs.myserver.net/tfs/DefaultCollection");
VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
ItemSet items;  

var identityManagementService = tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
var collectionWideValidUsers = identityManagementService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName,
                                                          "Project Collection Valid Users",
                                                          MembershipQuery.Expanded,
                                                          ReadIdentityOptions.None);


Console.WriteLine("Please wait while retrieving necessary information from {0}:", TfsRepository);
var validMembers = identityManagementService.ReadIdentities(collectionWideValidUsers.Members,
                                                            MembershipQuery.Expanded,
                                                            ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);
var memberNames = validMembers
          .Where(_ => !_.IsContainer && _.Descriptor.IdentityType != "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.UnauthenticatedIdentity")
          .Select(_ => _.UniqueName)
          .OrderBy(_ => _)
          .ToList();

string[] permissions;
bool UserCheck = false;
if (memberNames != null && items != null)
{
    foreach (var userName in memberNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Querying User: {0}\n", userName);
        for (int i = 0; i >= items.Items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items.Items[i].ItemType == ItemType.Folder)
            {
                string TfsRepositoryDir = items.Items[i].ServerItem;
                Console.WriteLine("    Checking:{0}", TfsRepositoryDir);
                permissions = vcs.GetEffectivePermissions(userName, TfsRepositoryDir);

                if (permissions != null && permissions.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string perm in permissions)
                    {
                        if (perm.ToLower() == "checkin" || perm.ToLower() == "merge")
                            UserCheck = true;
                    }

                    if (UserCheck)
                    {
                        string.Join(", ", permissions);
                        Console.Write("User: {0}:  Repo: {1}: Permissions:{2} \n ", userName, TfsRepositoryDir, string.Join(", ", permissions));
                        UserCheck = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you may have guessed, that it would take a very long time, as number of users are less than the folders we have in our repository. So querying every folder for a user's permission takes a hell of a time.

**Question:** I'm looking for a method, to query each user for its specific folder permissions. e.g I want to query a user "Ahmed" for how many folders it has access for checkin and merge. How to achieve this?

Comment: So the only thing wrong with the current code is that it takes too long?

Comment: You pass in a TFS folder as a parameter, then for each user in the system you want to see their permissions on that folder and all subfolders?  Does your userbase span across multiple Team Projects or Team Project Collections?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud. Yes, that's the main issue.

Comment: @baultista. Yes, that is the requirement. I'm only working with one projects, but the that may be the case for both scenarios.

Comment: Does my new script solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple script which quickly pulls all path-specific permissions for all users.  Modify as needed.  The trick you were missing is that not only does [`GetPermissions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138945.aspx) pull permissions recursively but also it pulls who the permissions are applied to.

If you need permissions only for specific users, you can use [a different `GetPermissions` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138946.aspx) instead.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System.Configuration;

void Main()
{
    string TfsRepository = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFS_Repository"];
    string TfsUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFS_URI"];
    TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TfsUri));
    ttpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
    var data = ttpc
        .GetService<VersionControlServer>()
        .GetPermissions(new string[] { TfsRepository }, RecursionType.Full)
        .SelectMany(rr => rr.Entries.Select(itm => new { itm, rr.ServerItem }))
        .Where(rr=>rr.itm.Allow.Length != 0)
        .Select(rr => new { 
            User = rr.itm.IdentityName,
            Path = rr.ServerItem,
            Permissions = String.Join(",", rr.itm.Allow)
        })
        .OrderBy(itm=>itm.User).ThenBy(itm=>itm.Path);
}
```